# Gaussianblur C++ programming and CUDA

Tags: gpu, gaussianblur

I made a CUDA C++ programming code for Gaussian blur. But I have a problem with my CPU image. It doesn't blur  but the GPU image does. At the end, my CPU image is always black. I can't generate a CPU image which is blurred. My GPU image comes out with many pixel layers on the image